# What is the name and effect behind this circular cloud phenomenon?

Tags: meteorology, clouds

The picture of this cloudy sky was taken today in Hamburg, Germany. Any idea, what it is, where it comes from and if it has a special name?

[image]

Comment: Possibly a [lenticular cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_cloud).

Comment: Thanks @Fred, while I have never seen a lenticular cloud in reality, I so far thought it typically can be found behind mountain ridges, but not over the relatively flat area over Hamburg.